# In Zabbix, how do I prevent triggers from firing based on another trigger's status?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

**Here is my current setup:**

[image: Here is my current setup.]

Basically, I have one trigger that runs a web scenario every 15 seconds to see if my service is online.

Then, I have two other triggers that run web scenarios every 60 seconds that make calls to the tool to check the status of multiple components.

When 'Tool is not online' is triggered, then the other two triggers will not fire, thanks to my expression I set. That's working as expected.

**The Problem**

When 'Tool is not online' goes away—in other words: the tool has come back online, the other triggers that were once not firing, now fire and show up under Monitoring... that is, until they run again and are able to connect to the tool and the web scenarios get the HTTP code and String value they require.

**Example**

1. Tool goes offline
2. 'Tool is not online' runs web scenario, webs scenario fails, trigger fires
3. 'More than 5 tickets...' and 'One or more integrated...' run and their web scenario fails, but 'Tool is not online' is also triggered, so they do not trigger (as per expression shown)
4. Tool goes online, 'Tool is not online' trigger goes away
5. **Problem:** The triggers from #3 which were not firing due to the status of 'Tool is not online' now are triggered as the expression is met, and show up under the Monitoring tab
6. The triggers from #3 run their web scenario check again and they go away

Comment: You use Zabbix 2.4?

Comment: @AlexanderT Yes